# Handling repeating rows when exporting spreadsheet to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, libreoffice-calc, export-to-xml

I have a very large spreadsheet that I'm trying to export to XML. Any row with repeating cells are skipped over during the transformation. So if a row has 
    1 2 2 2 3 4 5
only the first 2 will be copied to the XML file. I've found out this is because of how the spreadsheet stores repeating rows. I need my XSLT file to handle repeating cells in a row instead of skipping them.

I'm using LibreOffice Calc to do the transformations.

Here's the part of my sample .xslt file that does the heavy lifting:

```
<xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet/table:table">

   <xsl:for-each select="table:table-row[position() &gt; 0]">

   <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

   <Column>

     <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

     <p1><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[1]/text:p" /></p1> 
     <p1><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[2]/text:p" /></p1> 
     <p2><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[3]/text:p" /></p2> 
     <p3><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[4]/text:p" /></p3> 
     <p4><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[5]/text:p" /></p4> 
     <p5><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[6]/text:p" /></p5> 
     <p6><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[7]/text:p" /></p6> 

      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

      </Column>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Edit: Here's what my sample spreadsheet looks like in LibreOffice:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
12  12  13  14  15
15  15  15  15  15
17  17  18  18  17
```

And the resulting XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

<Column>
<p1>1</p1><p1>2</p1><p2>3</p2><p3>4</p3><p4>5</p4><p5/><p6/>
</Column>

<Column>
<p1>6</p1><p1>7</p1><p2>8</p2><p3>9</p3><p4>10</p4><p5/><p6/>
</Column>

<Column>
<p1>12</p1><p1>13</p1><p2>14</p2><p3>15</p3><p4/><p5/><p6/>
</Column>

<Column>
<p1>15</p1><p1/><p2/><p3/><p4/><p5/><p6/>
</Column>

 <Column>
 <p1>17</p1><p1>18</p1><p2>17</p2><p3/><p4/><p5/><p6/>
 </Column></root>
```

Comment: Can you also post the offending xml from the spreadsheet file?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited original post with my test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Open Document `*.ods` files cells which are identically are not stored redundant. Instead the first cell will have a attribute `table:number-columns-repeated` which tells the count of repeating: `<table:table-cell table:number-columns-repeated="2" ...>`.

So `XSLT` which transforms this to `XML`which needs all elements must generating elements repeatedly. Since we need using `XSLT 1.0`, this is not as simple as it should. We need a template which calls itself recursively.

Also your numbered element names `p1`, `p2`, ... does not making things easier. To achieve this and having the numbering according the resulting output elements instead of the input elements we must collecting the output elements in a variable first and then numbering that collection.

And your elements names are confusing. What you are calling `Column` are rows and the `p` elements are cells. So I have renamed them accordingly.

So having the following sheet:

[image]

and using export XSLT of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
 xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" 
 xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
 xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="office table text exsl">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="sheet">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/office:body" />
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office:body">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet/table:table">

  <xsl:for-each select="table:table-row">
   <xsl:element name="row">

   <xsl:variable name="thecells">

    <xsl:for-each select="table:table-cell">

     <xsl:variable name="repeated">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@table:number-columns-repeated">
        <xsl:value-of select="@table:number-columns-repeated" />
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:call-template name="repeatecells">
      <xsl:with-param name="start" select="1" />
      <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$repeated"/>
     </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:for-each>

   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($thecells)/cell">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('cell', position())}"><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></xsl:element>
   </xsl:for-each>

   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="repeatecells">
  <xsl:param name="start"/>
  <xsl:param name="end"/>

  <xsl:if test="not($start > $end)">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$start = $end">
     <xsl:element name="cell"><xsl:value-of select="text:p" /></xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:variable name="mid" select= "floor(($start + $end) div 2)"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="repeatecells">
      <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$mid"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
     <xsl:call-template name="repeatecells">
      <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$mid+1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$end"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sheet>
<row><cell1>P1</cell1><cell2>P2</cell2><cell3>P3</cell3><cell4>P4</cell4><cell5>P5</cell5><cell6>P6</cell6></row>
<row><cell1>1</cell1><cell2>1</cell2><cell3>1</cell3><cell4>1</cell4><cell5>2</cell5><cell6>2</cell6></row>
<row><cell1>1</cell1><cell2>2</cell2><cell3>2</cell3><cell4>2</cell4><cell5>2</cell5><cell6>3</cell6></row>
<row><cell1>1</cell1><cell2>1</cell2><cell3>1</cell3><cell4>2</cell4><cell5>2</cell5><cell6>2</cell6></row>
<row><cell1/><cell2>1</cell2><cell3>1</cell3><cell4/><cell5>2</cell5><cell6>2</cell6></row>
<row><cell1>1</cell1><cell2/><cell3/><cell4>2</cell4><cell5/><cell6/></row></sheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're using XSLT; but if you wanted to read the content.xml of the spreadsheet directly, a quick and easy fix for this is to make your numeric values formulas.

So instead of the cell having a value of `1`, give it a value of `=1`.